# Failed opening Mage/Searchautocomplete/Model/Processor.php

Tags: autocomplete

In my system log I am getting below error. Please help me to resolve it.

> ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Searchautocomplete/Model/Processor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in

Comment: It seems like a corrupted install of a 3rd party module with the name "Searchautocomplete". Consult with the module developer regarding this.

Comment: Compilation enable or disabled in admin side?

Answer (score 3):

If this is a Cmsmart extension (commonly found in Template Monster templates), more specifically Cmsmart AjaxSearch, then try updating

```
app/code/local/Cmsmart/Ajaxsearch/etc/config.xml
```

Change: `<class>searchautocomplete/processor</class>` (around line 29) 
to: `<class>ajaxsearch/processor</class>`

If that doesn't do the trick, check to see if your site is compiled and, if so, disable compilation and clear the compiled version.

Try this:

In the Admin panel, disable Compilation under **System>Tools>Compilation**.

In the command line, from the root directory, `php shell/compiler.php --clear`.  This will clear the compiled files (disabling is not necessarily enough).

Then clear cache and refresh your pages a couple times to see if the error message persists in system.log.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you enabled the Magento Compilation and the code was not compiled properly after the new installation / upgrade.

To solve this issue you need to disable Magento Compilation temporarily before any module installation / upgrade. To do this go to **System > Tools > Compilation.**

As soon the installation / upgrade went success, enable Magento Compilation same as before.